# Cakephp View Helper

Tags: cakephp

Whenever I'm displaying a user's name in my view file, I use:

```
echo $user['User']['name'];
```

The users table also has a 'company_name' field. If the user has a company name listed (in most cases, but not all), I would like to display their company name (and if they do not, I want to use the 'name' field). The code would look something like:

```
if(isset($user['User']['company_name']) && $user['User']['company_name'] != '') {
    echo $user['User']['company_name'];
} else {
    echo $user['User']['name'];
}
```

What is the proper way to handle this throughout multiple view files? Should I create a helper for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that this particular use case is such a small bit of presentation logic it would make more sense to me to build this within the scope of an [Element](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements) rather than a Helper.

Now if at some point down the road (or now even) you decide that there is more functionality that you would like to extend similar to this presentation logic, perhaps in the form of a UsersHelper that would define various pieces of display logic relevant to the current user, then it would be wise to encapsulate that functionality within a Helper.

Here's a good example to get you started with Elements:

```
// In src/Template/Element/name_display.ctp
if(isset($user['User']['company_name']) && $user['User']['company_name'] != '') {
    echo $user['User']['company_name'];
} else {
    echo $user['User']['name'];
}
```

In your view file:

```
// Echo this wherever you need the name displayed
echo $this->element('name_display', [
    'user' => $user // Sets the $user viewVar in the element
]);
```

And for sake of completeness, in your controller:

```
$this->set('user', $user);
```

In your spare time it would be a good idea just to check out the manual on some of the core helpers that are included with Cake to get an idea of how they are constructed to get a better idea of use cases in which you would want to create a Helper.

[2.x Elements Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)

[3.x Elements Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)

[2.x Helpers Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html)

[3.x Helpers Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)

Good luck!